# Import flask_wtf works fine with jupyter notebook but command prompt rises error

Tags: python, flask

jupyter notebook runs the code:
`from flask_wtf import FlaskForm`
with no problem

but command prompt rises error:
ModuleNotFoundError:no module named flask_wtf

maybe has to do with anaconda?

I have tried to run the solution from the instructor so there would be no typo, but flask_wtf still can not be found.

I only have one version of python,

I am not using a virtual environment

I have installed Flask-WTF with pip and conda

pip install flask_wtf shows satisfied already

conda install flask_wtf shows not found in the channels.

Comment: just to check capitalization, the pip module is `Flask-WTF` and the module is `flask_wtf` right? it worked for me.

Comment: but thats what the offical documents says: pip install Flask-WTF and from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

Comment: yes I was checking that you were doing it that way... hmm.. if you run `pip show -f Flask-WTF` it should show the file location under the `Location:` heading, can you check that that is a correct place and the files are indeed there? also showing `sys.path` might also be necessary.

Comment: I uninstalled then reinstalled multiple times, but one thing is that, since I have anaconda, it is under conda lib, idk if that s the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what is going wrong but I can offer at least a temporary fix.  If you run `pip show Flask-WTF` it will show the location (folder) where the package is installed (bolded in below output)

```
 ~ % python3 -m pip show Flask-WTF
Name: Flask-WTF
Version: 0.14.3
Summary: Simple integration of Flask and WTForms.
Home-page: https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf
Author: Dan Jacob
Author-email: danjac354@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: WTForms, Flask, itsdangerous
Required-by:
```

In order to import the module this folder must be in the `sys.path` list, you can check if it is by doing `"path" in sys.path` from an interpreter:

```
>>> import sys
>>> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages" in sys.path
True
```

If this gives you `True` and you are unable to import the module I have no idea what is wrong and I would blame anaconda and install python from [the official site.](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

If this gives `False` I would still blame anaconda for having pip install to a location that isn't even used by python, but at least in that case I can offer a fix, you can simply add the folder to `sys.path` at the start of your program:

```
import sys
# this path would be different for you, what ever is shown under `Location:` in `pip show Flask-WTF`
sys.path.append("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages")
import flask_wtf
```

I hope this is at least enough to unblock you so you can keep programming.  I'm not sure how to even determine what is actually going wrong.